# WebDriver switch to browser opened after click on button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver with JAVA , I'm trying to automate a feature where I have to open a new tab to do some operations there and back to the previous tab ( Father) .

He loses the session and error.

//when I click here it opens the modal

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnSimulateDK")).click();
```

I tried this way , if I put login and password error on this page , it may already open with the current session and show the activities that I can perform .

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnSimulateDK")).click();

                        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
                           if (!winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore))      
                    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

                      if(driver.getTitle().equals("Title of target window")){
                            //perform operation on target window
                           }
                      }
                        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);


     }
```

[image: Java Selenium]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IEDRIVER has problems when there are other sessions open , just close them in the task manager and the problem is solved .

[session cookie lost when click made to a link that opens a window with window.open()](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1486)

Answer (score 1):

driver.getWindowHandles() doesn't guarantee any order  and it also includes the current window(Father).

So rather than just switching to window

you need to check winHandle is not equal to winHandleBefore

and if so then only perform switchTo()

Also it is better to ensure that you are landed on correct page.

like

```
  for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
       if (!winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore))      
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

       if(driver.getTitle().equals("Title of target window")){
        //perform operation on target window
       }
  }
```

Comment: I changed the code and gave the same error, edited the question with the new code

Comment: could you please post what error message you are getting?